# How to exclude 404 pages from python downloading

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib2

This code works fine, but how do I stop 404 pages from downloading? Urllib requests always return 403 because the host does not allow python. Is there another way to detect if the file exists?

```
import requests
import os
while True:
  id = input("Enter ID:")
  if os.path.exists("1.mp3"):
    os.remove("1.mp3")
  url = 'http://www.texture.ml/kcl/{0}.mp3'.format(id)
  r = requests.get(url)
  with open("1.mp3", 'wb') as f:
    f.write(r.content)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to just add a check for it. For example

```py
import requests
import os
while True:
  id = input("Enter ID:")
  if os.path.exists("1.mp3"):
    os.remove("1.mp3")
  url = 'http://www.texture.ml/kcl/{0}.mp3'.format(id)
  r = requests.get(url)
  if r.status_code != 404:
    with open("1.mp3", 'wb') as f:
      f.write(r.content)
```